# EasyMock issue using addThrow to expect Exception

Tags: exception, testng, easymock

I am trying to run the EasyMock example given [here](https://sites.google.com/a/pintailconsultingllc.com/java/easymock-examples) with TestNG and am facing a strange issue. The first two tests run fine but the third Test (getPriceDataAccessThrowsRuntimeException) runs successfully if I run it alone. However, when I run it with other two test either individually or all together the third test fails and I get the following:

```
FAILED: getPriceDataAccessThrowsRuntimeException
org.testng.TestException: 
Expected exception java.lang.RuntimeException but got org.testng.TestException: 
Expected exception java.lang.RuntimeException but got java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call DataAccess.getPriceBySku("3283947"):
```

Following is the Test code:

```
@Test
public void getPrice() throws Exception {
    // Set expectations on mocks.
    expect(mockedDependency.getPriceBySku(SKU)).andReturn(new BigDecimal(100));

    // Set mocks into testing mode.
    replay(mockedDependency);
    final BigDecimal price = systemUnderTest.getPrice(SKU);
    assertNotNull(price);

    // Verify behavior.
    verify(mockedDependency);
}

@Test(expectedExceptions = MyCustomException.class)
public void getPriceNonExistentSkuThrowsException() throws Exception {

    // Set expectations on mocks.
    expect(mockedDependency.getPriceBySku(BAD_SKU)).andReturn(null);

    // Set mocks into testing mode.
    replay(mockedDependency);
    final BigDecimal price = systemUnderTest.getPrice(BAD_SKU);
}

@Test(expectedExceptions = RuntimeException.class)
public void getPriceDataAccessThrowsRuntimeException() throws Exception {

    // Set expectations on mocks.
    expect(mockedDependency.getPriceBySku(SKU)).andThrow(new RuntimeException("Fatal data access exception."));

    // Set mocks into testing mode.
    replay(mockedDependency);
    final BigDecimal price = systemUnderTest.getPrice(SKU);
}
```

Any idea guys, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've made a mistake when converting from JUnit to TestNG. In the [linked example](https://sites.google.com/a/pintailconsultingllc.com/java/easymock-examples), the `doBeforeEachTestCase` method is run before each test case and this resets the mocked dependency to its base state. You haven't included all the code: you should have `doBeforeEachTestCase` [annotated](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations) with `BeforeMethod` to run it with TestNG.

Comment: Thanks so much, how could I miss that! Been a while I wrote my tests.